# Functional inheritance using the YouTube API

Tags: javascript, mvc, youtube

I'm looking for some feedback on my implementation of MVC and functional inheritance (as described by Douglas Crockford in his book *The Good Parts*) in an app that uses the YouTube API.

This is my first time building anything remotely object-oriented so I'd really appreciate some advice on this app.

You can view the app in full [here](http://ec2-46-137-6-89.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com/youTube/). Here are some relevant code snippets:

Model:

```
models.YTData = function(data) {
    var feed = data.feed,
        entries = feed.entry,
        length = entries.length,
        newData = {vids: []};

        for(var i = 0; i < length; i+=1) {
            var index = (i + 1) % 5,
                entry = entries[i],
                date = entry.published.$t,
                jsDate = new Date(date.substring(0, 4), date.substring(5, 7) - 1, date.substring(8, 10)),
                todayDate = new Date(),
                oneDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24,
                views = entry.yt$statistics.viewCount,
                numOfDays = Math.ceil((todayDate.getTime() - jsDate.getTime()) / oneDay);

            if (entry.media$group.media$content !== undefined) {
                newData.vids.push({
                    title: entry.title.$t,
                    url:  entry.media$group.media$content[0].url,
                    index: index === 0 ? index + 5 : (i + 1) % 5,
                    views: controllers.addCommas('' + views),
                    date: '' + jsDate.getUTCDate() + ' ' + controllers.utilFunctions(jsDate.getMonth()).convertMonth() + ' ' + jsDate.getFullYear(),
                    average: controllers.addCommas('' + Math.round(views / numOfDays))
                });
            }

            else {
                continue;
            }
        }
    localStorage.vids = JSON.stringify(newData);
    return newData;
};
```

Controller:

```
controllers.request = function(obj) {
                var obj = obj || {};
                var that = {
                    base_url: 'https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds',
                    max_results: 25,
                    start_index: obj.start_index || 1,
                    alt: 'alt=json-in-script',
                    country: obj.country ? '/' + obj.country : '',
                    genre: obj.genre ? '&category=' + obj.genre : '',
                    call_url: function() {
                        return that.base_url + that.country + '/on_the_web_Music' + '?max-results=' + 
                              that.max_results + '&start-index=' + that.start_index + '&' + 
                              that.alt + that.genre;
                    },
                    ajax: function() {
                        views.loading();
                        $.ajax({
                            type: 'GET',
                            url: that.call_url(),
                            dataType: 'JSONP',
                            error: function() {
                                views.serverError().hide();
                            },
                            success: function(data) {
                                var loading = views.loading;
                                views.loading = function() {};
                                if (data.feed.entry === undefined) {
                                    views.noResults().hide();
                                }

                                else {
                                    views.displayFirst(models.YTData(data)).pager(obj.genre, obj.country);
                                }
                                views.loading = loading;
                            }
                        });
                    }
                };
                return that;
    };
```

Views (showing an example of functional inheritance):

```
views.display = function(data) {
    var that = {
        vids: data.vids,
        condition: data.vids.length >= 5 ? 5 : data.vids.length,
        hideCurrentVids: function() {
            $('.playerContainer').animate({opacity: 0}, 500, function() {
                that.showVids.apply(that);
            });
        },

        showVids: function() {
                $('#vids').html(views.tplVids(data)).css('opacity', '1');
                $('#loader').css('display', 'none');
                for (var i = 0; i < this.condition; i += 1) {
                    views.loadVideo(this.vids[i].url, false, i + 1);
                    $('#player' + (i + 1))
                        .parent()
                        .parent()
                        .css({position: 'relative', top: 0})
                        .delay(i * 500)
                        .animate({opacity: 1}, 1000);
                }
                $('#videos').removeData('loading');
                $('#loader').css('display', 'none');
        }

    }
    return that;
};

views.displayFirst = function(data) {
    var that = views.display(data); // inherits from views.display
    that.length = data.vids.length;
    that.pagerArray = {pagerItems: []};
    that.counter = 0;
    that.pager = function(genre, country) {
        if (this.length > 5) {
            for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i += 5) {
                this.counter += 1;
                this.pagerArray.pagerItems.push({
                    index: this.counter
                });
            }
            document.getElementById('pager').innerHTML = views.pagerGen(this.pagerArray);
            $('#pager').animate({
                opacity: 1
            }, 500);
            data.vids.splice(5);
        }

        else {
            $('#pager').empty();
        }
        this.showVids();
        views.viewing(genre, country);
    };
    return that;
};
```

Comment: Your controller has SEVEN levels of indentation, if your levels of identation have gone over 4 then your doing it wrong, break your functions into smaller ones

Comment: @Raynos Thanks for your response. Good point - I had thought my functions were a bit bloated.

Comment: Sorry, I'm having a problem finding the functional inheritance bit in your view ... That's a lot of code :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a JavaScript expert, so just a few general notes:

1. ```
   var index = (i + 1) % 5,
   ...
   index: index === 0 ? index + 5 : (i + 1) % 5,
   ```

   If I'm right, it could be written as:

   ```
   index: index === 0 ? 5 : index,
   ```
2. I'd use a guard clause here:

   ```
   if (entry.media$group.media$content !== undefined) {
       newData.vids.push({
           ...
       });
   }
   else {
       continue;
   }
   ```

   So, it would look like this:

   ```
   if (entry.media$group.media$content === undefined) {
       continue;
   }

   newData.vids.push({
       ...
   });
   ```

   References: *Replace Nested Conditional with Guard Clauses* in *Refactoring: Improving the Design of Existing Code*; [Flattening Arrow Code](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/01/flattening-arrow-code.html)
3. Instead of

   ```
   condition: data.vids.length >= 5 ? 5 : data.vids.length,
   ```

   use `Math.min`:

   ```
   condition: Math.min(data.vids.length, 5),
   ```

   I think it's easier to read.